# How to disabled analytics tracking for specific type requests?

Tags: experience-analytics, tracking

We do not want certain request to be tracked for analytics data say for example `API` calls.

How we can achieve this using Sitecore `config` change?

We are using Sitecore 8.2 update 3.

Answer (score 2):

The `Sitecore.config` file has a node called `tracking/untrackedPages`. Sitecore does not track files that are listed in this node. By default, these files are not tracked.

We can add entry to avoid tracing for `API`-calls setting path attribute `/api/*`.

See below config setting:

```
<tracking>
    <untrackedPages>
      <add path="/api/*" />
      <add path="/sitecore/default.aspx" />
      <add path="/sitecore/service/error.aspx" />
      <add path="/sitecore/service/Heartbeat.aspx" />
      <add path="/sitecore/service/keepalive.aspx" />
      <add path="/sitecore/service/nolicense.aspx" />
    </untrackedPages>
  </tracking>
```

Files are referenced by their relative URLs. There is also a `tracking/untrackedPages` node in the `App_Config\Include\ Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config` file. Sitecore merges the nodes when it read the config files.

The ***recommended*** way to add files is using patch files instead of editing the config files directly. This file describes the include file patch process.

You can access the list of pages that are untracked in code by using the `UntrackedPages` property of the `Sitecore.Analytics.Configuration.AnalyticsSettings` class.

Comment: I think you're missing the fact that this is dependent on custom code such as https://github.com/jvtroyen/Sitecore.UntrackedPages. The built-in `Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.CheckPreconditions` processor does not include this functionality.